# Lucene remove stopwords from file

Tags: java, nlp

I'm new to Lucene and I wish to remove stopwords from sentences in a large text file. Every sentence is stored on a separate line in the text file. The code I have currently is:

```
    Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_41, new StringReader("if everyone got spam from me im extremely sorry"));

    final StandardFilter standardFilter = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_41, tokenizer);
    final StopFilter stopFilter = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_41, standardFilter, sa.getStopwordSet());

    final CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = tokenizer.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

    try{
        stopFilter.reset();

        while(stopFilter.incrementToken()) {
            final String token = charTermAttribute.toString().toString();
            System.out.printf("%s ", token);
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){

    }
```

However, as you can see the StringReader only has one predefined sentence. Now, I was wondering how can it be done so I can have the program read in all sentences from my text file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to point a StringReader at a file? Is that your question?

Comment: Yes. As of now I only read in one sentence but I have a whole file containing thousands of sentences and I wish the program to read them all and remove the stop words from all those sentences.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.   Are you trying to read in a file line by line, remove stop words, and then write the lines back out?   If so, then Lucene is not the tool you want to use.   If you are trying to read in a file line by line and make an index to search against then you should be creating an IndexWriter using a StandardAnalyzer and looping through your file line by line and create documents for each line.

Comment: I wish to read in a file line by line, remove stop words and write the lines back out. Which tool can you recommend that allows for stop word removal and lemmatization?

Comment: Removing stop words, I would just do it myself.   You could even rip the default set from Lucene if you wanted and remove the words.   You didn't have anything about Lemmatization in your example.